# Calendar View Change Column Position in Calendar List

Tags: list, content-type, list-view, calendar

I have created Calendar List in SharePoint farm.
I have attached Custom Content type to list and set as default.
after that I have attached new column in Content type,
then something wired happen and the default Position of Calendar Columns in Calendar View get change.

as you can see in screen shot Start Time column is currently at bottom. 
[image]

I have tried to change ordering by going to list settings-->Calendar View.
But not able to change the position.

Please help me here

Comment: have you tried changin the column order by selecting the content type from the list settings?

Comment: HarryB Thanks just change column position by going List settings --> Content type --> Column order

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what I found by googling, I got the Column Order link to show up only after DISABLING management of content types.

List Settings > Advanced settings > Allow management of content types? > No

Comment: If Content Type management is enabled, column order is modified in the content type.  If Content Type management is disabled, column order is modified in list settings.